# How to simulate an Appearance ("dark mode") change in React Native using Jest?

Tags: react-native, unit-testing, jestjs, react-native-testing-library

I am writing a puzzle app in React Native where the user can solve a puzzle by changing their device's Appearance to dark mode. I'm using React Native's [Appearance](https://reactnative.dev/docs/appearance) module to accomplish this, by calling Appearance.getColorScheme() to get the initial color scheme, and registering an event listener for when the color scheme changes using Appearance.addChangeListener() within the useEffect hook:

```
useEffect(() => {
      const originalColorScheme = Appearance.getColorScheme();

      Appearance.addChangeListener((event) => {
        if (Appearance.getColorScheme() !== originalColorScheme) {
          setSolved(true);
        }
      });
    }, []);
```

This is working fine, but I'd like to be able to unit test my component by simulating a change to dark mode in Jest and/or React Native Testing Library (or similar), after which I can check for changes to the content of the page (a "congratulations" message, in this case).

In my mind, it could look something like:

```
const text = await screen.findByText("good luck!");
// fireEvent("changeColorScheme", { colorScheme: "dark" });
const text2 = await screen.findByText("congratulations!");
```

Is anything like this possible? I'm guessing it has something to do with mocks, but it's a little over my head at the moment. Thanks for any help you can provide!